# userSession is null after Auth.signUp with "autoSignIn" enabled (AWS Cognito)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I need to get the jwtToken from the `Auth.signUp`. Is this possible if i enable `autoSignIn:{enabled:true}`?

```
  const signUp = async () => {
      await Auth.signUp({
        username: email,
        password,
        attributes: {
          email, // optional
          name,
        },
        autoSignIn:{
          enabled: true
        }
      })
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data.user); //user.signInUserSession is null
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          if (err.message) {
            setInvalidMessage(err.message);
          }
          console.log(err);
        });
       await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
        .then(user =>{
          console.log(user)
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error) //"User is not authenticated"
        })
  };
```

I call I want the jwttoken from the userSession data for conditional rendering and I store the token in my router.js. The response object from `Auth.signUp` contains a `CognitoUser` which has a `signInUserSession` value but its's null.

EDIT: Tried to call `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()` after but yields an error that user is not authenticated. But when i restart my app, the user will be authenticated. I still cant authenticate user on the same app "instance"

Comment: Did you try it out? What was the result?

Comment: i get the `<ISignUpResult>` response as expected, but not sure how to manipulate this to get what i need. I also cant find any details of `<ISignUpResult>` and what it should contain.

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/4644b4322ee260165dd756ca9faeb235445000e3/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js/index.d.ts#L136-L139) you should be able to use `getSignInUserSession()` on the user object.

Comment: it returns null. I tried accessing it through the method and dot notation (user.signInUserSession , const sess = user.getSignInUserSession()) and neither works. Ive also discovered that if i signup, then restart my app, it will be signed in when the app loads the next time which means there is a valid `signInUserSession` on next load. not sure why

Comment: i am also using lambda function as cognito trigger for pre-confirmSignup if that affects it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { Auth, Hub } from 'aws-amplify';
const listener = (data) => {
    switch (data.payload.event) {
      case 'autoSignIn':
        console.log('auto sign in successful');
        console.log(data.payload) //returns user data including session and tokens. 
        //other logic with user data
        break;
    }
  };
```

Above is the code to initalize the `Hub` listener provided by `amplify` api. Ater user presses sign up, I called to get user session data when user is automatically signed in.

```
Hub.listen('auth', listener)
```